# транслятор Nasm\Yasm написание драйвера

Tags: ассемблер

Можно ли писать драйвера на  NASM для windows и linux ? 
Можно ли писать драйвера на YASM для windows и linux ?

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Драйверы (как и всё остальное) можно писать на любом ассемблере, который поддерживается на целевой платформе. Нужно ли - другой вопрос.